# Apply cubic root transformation and StandardScaler to some specific columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I do have a data frame with so many cols. I would like to apply cbrt transformation first and then StandardScaler() to some specific cols in a dataframe for each month but I received some errors

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'month':['1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2','2','2'],'X1': 
[30,42,25,32,12,10,4,6,5,10,24,21],'X2':[10,76,100,23,65,94,67,24,67,54,87,81],'X3': 
[23,78,95,52,60,76,68,92,34,76,34,12]})
df
```

My code below is but no worries about Month

```
df['X1']=pd.Series(np.cbrt(df['X1'])).values
```

Below is for but needs to consider group month

```
  from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
  scaler = StandardScaler()
  df['X1_scale'] = scaler.group('Month').fit(df['X1'])
```

I would like to combine these two operations on a autamated function that adds column X1_Scale and X2_Scale but since I have so many cols I would like to do this on first 2 cols (df.loc[:,2:3]) in general. Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `np.cbrt` to calculate the element wise cube root on the first two columns followed by `groupby` on `month` and transformation using `zscore` to calculate the standard score of each sample per unique month.

```
from scipy.stats import zscore

c = df.columns[1:3]
df[c + '_Scale'] = np.cbrt(df[c]).groupby(df['month']).transform(zscore)
```

---

```
   month  X1   X2  X3  X1_Scale  X2_Scale
0      1  30   10  23  0.286075 -1.531934
1      1  42   76  78  1.220298  0.705876
2      1  25  100  95 -0.178042  1.142135
3      1  32   23  52  0.457241 -0.790689
4      1  12   65  60 -1.785572  0.474613
5      2  10   94  76  0.004353  1.026875
6      2   4   67  68 -1.208026  0.093139
7      2   6   24  92 -0.716861 -2.171608
8      2   5   67  34 -0.945947  0.093139
9      2  10   54  76  0.004353 -0.449041
10     2  24   87  34  1.565310  0.804088
11     2  21   81  12  1.296817  0.603408
```